# Installing PHP7 with Homebrew on Mac

Tags: laravel, homebrew, laravel-valet

When I try to install PHP7 on Homebrew I get this error

```
Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /usr/sbin/apxs follows:
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.

configure: error: Aborting
```

Does any one have a solution for this, knowing that I've searching the web for a solution without any luck

Comment: What command did you issue? To install. To run.

Comment: @MarkSetchell brew install homebrew/php/php70

Comment: i use the following
    ````brew tap homebrew/dupes````
    ````brew tap homebrew/php````
    ````brew install php70````